# Alternative use of ⊕ symbol

Tags: notation, direct-sum

I am aware that the symbol "⊕" usually denotes direct sum in algebraic applications.  I am currently looking at a code of practice document for the design of stainless steel tanks which uses the symbol in the following manner:

R/T ⊕ 10

Where R is the radius of the knuckle of a tank, and T is the wall thickness - i.e. it is specifying something with regard to the ratio of the two.

I have never seen the symbol used (misused?) in this manner before. I am trying to ascertain what the intended meaning of the symbol is in this context.  Is it supposed to mean "approximately" or something to that effect in this case?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: I haven't seen it before either. It's always possible it was meant to be some other symbol like $\approx$ and it is just showing up wrong. We'll probably need some more context. Are there any clues before or after this line that explain the relationship between $10$ and the ratio?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes, this is what I am leaning towards also - incorrect use of the symbol.  It is in print though (not online) so a little less likely that it is just a typo.  I know from my experience of these types of codes and standards that this will be likely to be either > or =.   In most design standards, this ratio would be set as a minimum value in order to ensure that sharp radii are avoided (because they create stress risers in general terms).

Comment: I’ve seen plenty of printed documents—especially older ones—in which because of either a font substitution or character encoding mismatch during printing incorrect symbols appear. Such errors often go uncorrected for years.